Pyserial 'Access Denied' Error when using shared COM port
I am currently running a python program where pyserial reads incoming serial data to then output given signals with an Arduino using pyfirmata based on that data received. However, this data needs to also be received by tera term. Which creates an issue since only 1 COM port is received.
To get around this, I downloaded HHD virtual serial port tools to create a virtual COM port so both can be used to their respective programs. Even after creating the virtual shared port I still get the access denied error.
For example, I created a virtual port 'COM16' from 'COM14'. If I open COM14 through tera term it reads the correct data but then when I try to run my python program reading from 'COM16' I get a access denied error.
Any ideas on how to get around this?

There is a very good reason why you are getting this error.  The operating system will not allow two different programs to use the same serial port at the same time.  Ask yourself what you want to happen if program 1 is in the middle of sending the string "Hello" when program 2 suddenly wants to send the string "world."  The port would transmit some garbled mess like "Helwloorld", which won't make sense to the receiver.  PySerial has the concept of "opening" and "closing" a port: "opening" a port prevents another program from using it; "closing" releases the port back to the OS.

the python program only needs to "listen" to the incoming data, so I thought with a virtual port that it would be able to work. Is there any work around to be able to listen on incoming COM data?

I would write a little Python web server, which would to relay the incoming serial data to any client that wanted to monitor it.  That will definitely work.  But there might be an easier solution - I have heard of something called a "serial port splitter."  https://freeserialportsplitter.com/.  I've never used one so I can't give you any more information.  Google "serial port splitter software" for more alternatives.

As an aside, even having multiple listeners to the same COM port can be tricky.  The port would have to make copies of each byte of incoming data, one copy for each of the listeners.  And it would have to keep track of which listener had processed which chunk of data, so that it didn't repeat data or omit data.  That would add a huge processing overhead to an otherwise simple situation, so this is generally not done by the operating system.  I assume that those "serial port splitters" I mentioned have found ways of solving these problems.

Thanks for the response, I did try a "Serial port splitter" HHD Vitrual serial port tools as stated in my question but I will give the one you suggested a try aswell incase my software was a fluke.
